# two data items in a single column, seperated by comma - SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

[image: please view the days header(sun,mon)]

i have two item in the days column ("sun,mon"). For getting the subject according to the day, i have to fire a query by comparing the individual day, but there are two or more days in a single column. how could this be done in #Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the SQL [`LIKE` operator](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like), which lets you use simple wildcards: `%` to match zero-or-more arbitrary characters, and `_` to match exactly one arbitrary character.

So you'd do:

```
SELECT stuff FROM mytable WHERE days LIKE '%sun%'
```

This will be slow if you have a lot of rows in that table, though. If that's the case, you'll need a different table design.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *FROM mytable WHERE days LIKE '%sun%'